# Checking for specific event in pygame event queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to be able to check for a user defined event in pygame `pygame.USERVENT+1` to be specific. I have my main loop where a window is filled and things are drawn to the window. I also have a for loop to check for events such as quitting or resizing the window. Then I have a function that I call called `draw_cursor()`. I am trying to check for the specific event of `pygame.USEREVENT+1` in this function so I could use it to draw an object however I cannot seem to get this event without using the event queue in the main function to check if `pygame.USERVENT+1`  is in the event queue.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width, height = 1024, 648
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)

pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)

def display_cursor():
    if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
        print("This should print when USERVENT is in the event queue")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.w, event.h
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.VIDEORESIZE)
        """if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            print("This will print when USEREVENT in the event queue")"""

    display_cursor()

    window.fill((0,0,255))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The commented out part is the part that would actually print when `pygame.USERVENT+1` is in the event queue. I use `pygame.event.poll().type` as this returns the events as a number and pygame.USERVENT+1 is number 24. I would think this would work as `pyame.event.poll().type` should return the number 24 when `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is in the event queue. I also had a look at: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.peek to also check in a similar way if the event is in the event queue. I tried `if pygame.event.peek(pygame.USEREVENT+1):` instead of `if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:` It still didn't print out what I wanted it to do.

I would like to be able to check the specific event `pygame.USERVEENT+1` only in this `display_cursor()` function and I am not using `pygame.event.get()` in a for loop just to check for one event as I have found it to slow down my program to a point where the window is barely responsive. Is there a way that I could only check for user defined events in a separate function without having to pass the event object to this function to stop it from slowing down? Is there also a parameter or similar function that I am missing that does exactly what I thought `pygame.event.poll()` or `pygame.event.peek()` did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. There are no more messages in the queue after `pygame.event.get()` has been called. Hence [`pygame.event.poll()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.poll) almost always returns an event object of type `pygame.NOEVENT` in `display_cursor`.

You need to call `display_cursor` in the event loop. The event must be an argument of the function:

```py
def display_cursor(event):
    if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
        print("This should print when USERVENT is in the event queue")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.w, event.h
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.VIDEORESIZE)
        """if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            print("This will print when USEREVENT in the event queue")"""
        display_cursor(event)
```

Alternatively, you can get the list of events and pass the list of events to the function:

```py
def display_cursor(event_list ):
    for event in event_list :
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            print("This should print when USERVENT is in the event queue")

while True:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.w, event.h
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.VIDEORESIZE)
        """if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            print("This will print when USEREVENT in the event queue")"""
        
    display_cursor(event_list)
```

See also [Faster version of pygame.event.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086113/faster-version-of-pygame-event-get/58087070#58087070)

If you're looking for a more nuanced approach, see [Pygame: how to write event-loop polymorphically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406647/pygame-how-to-write-event-loop-polymorphically/60408967#60408967)

Comment: Is there a possible way in doing the same thing without needing to have display_cursor() within the event queue

Comment: @Dextron I've extended the answer. There is no other option than the 2 options in the answer.